# Mark updated checkbox of a many-to-many relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, checkbox, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I am trying to show the updated checkboxes that are fetched from a many-to-many relationship.

Model `Candidato`:

```
public function estados()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(EstadoPostulacion::class, 'candidato_estado_postulacions', 'status_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();        
    }
```

Model `EstadoPostulacion`

```
public function candidatos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Candidato::class,  'candidato_estado_postulacions','user_id', 'status_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Model `CandidatoEstadoPostulacion`

```
public function candidatos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Candidato::class,  'status_id', 'user_id');
}

public function estados()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EstadoPostulacion::class, 'id', 'status_id');
}
```

Controller `Candidatos`

```
public function index( Vacancy $vacante, Candidato $candidato )
{
    $estados = EstadoPostulacion::pluck('status', 'id');

    $ca = Candidato::with('estados')->get();

    return view('candidatos.index', compact('vacante', 'estados', 'candidato') );
}
```

table `Candidatos`:

| id | user_id | vacancy_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

table `estado_postulaciones`:

| id | status |
| --- | --- |

table `candidato_estado_postulaciones`:

| status_id | user_id | vacancy_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

view `candidatos/index.blade.php`

```
 @forelse ($estados as $id => $estado)
     <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="status[]" id="{{ $estado }}-{{ $candidato->user_id }}" class="peer hidden" value="{{ $id }}" {{ $candidato->estados->contains($id) ? 'checked' : '' }} onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <label for="{{ $estado }}-{{ $candidato->user_id }}" class="block cursor-pointer select-none rounded-xl p-2 text-center peer-checked:bg-blue-500 peer-checked:font-bold peer-checked:text-white">
          <i class="fas fa-folder fa-2x"></i>
          <div class="w-full text-xs">Está en:</div>
          <div class="w-full text-xs text-gray-800 font-semibold uppercase">{{ $estado }}</div>
          </label>
   </div>
   @empty
      <li>No existe ningun estado en la BD</li>
   @endforelse
```

Image of what I need it to show:
[image: Image of what I need it to show]

Comment: Laravel many-to-many relationships are defined using `belongsToMany` method and not `hasMany`. Are you sure you have the correct relationship setup?

Comment: @guala you're right I already edited it, now what I need is for the checkboxes to appear marked according to the intermediate table, let's say there are several candidates that all have 5 states and said checkboxes appear marked.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand if *belongsToMany* is the right relation beteween *Candidato* and *EstadoPostulacion*, maybe for some translation problem.
I think you should also create a model *Status* and a table *statuses*, so, instead of `$estados = EstadoPostulacion::pluck('status', 'id');` you can get the statuses with `Status::all()` (or something similar).

Your specific problem is that you use `$candidato->estados->contains($id) ? 'checked' : ''` in your view, but since *estados* is a *belongsToMany* relation, it returns a *collection containing models* so it will never contains an element equal to *$id* and that expression will be ever *false*.
Also note that the class Model does not own a method called `contains()`.

Anyway I think that the closest thing that achieve what you want is something like:

```
$candidato->estados()->whereId($id)->exists() ? 'checked' : ''
```

#### Update

Considering the comment of @miken32 a better option could be using a *where* filter over the *estados* collection:

```
$candidato->estados->where('id', $id)->count() ? 'checked' : ''
```

Comment: No point in doing another DB query when you already have the collection. Just use `Collection::where()`.

Comment: @miken32 you are right, that is another possible option, in fact in the controller is done an eager loading: `$ca = Candidato::with('estados')->get();` but then is not used

Comment: @Pipo This is the relationship between candidates and estadoPostulacion and an intermediate table called CandidatoEstadoPostulacion was created.

The estadoPostulacion table carries the states shown in the image ("Applied", "seen", "Selected", "Finalist", "Discarded"), I haven't been able to solve it yet.

Comment: @Giancarlort, it's not completely clear what are you meaning. Perhaps does *estadoPostulacion* conatains the descriptions of all states avaiable and no other information or whatever?
If it's so, the correct relation is **Candidato** *belongsTo* **EstadoPostulacion** and you don't need *CandidatoEstadoPostulacion*
Please explain better the situation

Comment: @Pipo EstadoPostulacion has the name and description of the states, the Candidates table has id, user_id, vacancy_id (the candidate is a person who applies for a certain vacancy)

my applicants web route is: " Route::get('candiatos/{vacante}', [CandidatosController::class, 'index'])->name('candidatos.index');"

The recruiter activates the checkboxes of the states of the different candidates as in the image that I attached above, the states of said candidate and a certain vacancy are stored in an intermediate table CandidatesEstadoPostulacion with status_id, user_id, vacancy_id.

Comment: @Pipo From the intermediate table is where I update the checkboxes of the different candidates in their respective job vacancies CandidatesEstadoPostulacion

Comment: @Giancarlort, from the last comments I deduce that the relationships that have been set up between the tables are not optimal. I recommend this setting: **Candidato** *hasMany* **CandidatoEstadoPostulacion**, then **CandidatoEstadoPostulacion** *belongsTo*  **Candidato**, then remove **EstadoPostulacion** *belongsToMany* **Candidato**  - Note that in your initial question you don't mention to a *vacancy* column in *CandidatesEstadoPostulacion* model

Comment: @Pippo The relationship between Candidate and EstadoPostulaciones is from many to many, that is why the intermediate table CandidateEstadoPortulacion was created, the vacancy table refers to the vacancy in which the candidate applied, in the image there is only one applicant but there may be many more, it is assumed that many-to-many relationships are used belongsToMany

Comment: @Giancarlort, well maybe I can't get a complete picture of the situation. Anyway, lets's focus on the main problem: both *hasMany* and *belongsToMany* return a collection, so you can do a test with **tinker** (*php artisan tinker*): `Candidato::find(*HERE_AN_EXISTING_CANDIDATO_ID*)->estado->where('id', *HERE_AN_EXISTING_ESTADO_ID*)->count() ? 'checked' : 'not checked';`